# Find a record in Wpf datagrid by typing

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bound to Observable Members collection. Now i want to find a member in datagrid by typing the member name. I have tried IsTextSearchEnable property but it is not searching. Here is my xaml.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgOtherCharges" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="25" Grid.Row="4" AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.Text="Name"
              CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="Cell" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MembersCollection,Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLineColorBrush}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLineColorBrush}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonSelectedBrush}"  />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A8E3FC" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Member Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

i need a quick solution folks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView((DataContext as MyViewModel).MembersCollection);
      view.Filter = o => (o as Member).Name.Contains((sender as TextBox).Text);
}
```

I hope it was quick enough :)

Comment: i appreciate that. Would u mind to give something in xaml with datagrid instead of separate textbox

Comment: I mean how can i use property like IsTextSearchEnabled in xaml to make datagrid searchable

Comment: TextSearch is inherited from ItemsControl and as far as i know is not supported in DataGrid

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this question today to find a solution to the same problem. While `TextSearch` apparently was not available back in 2012, it currently is.

So for future reference, below my current solution for this problem with three added properties: `IsTextSearchCaseSensitive`, `IsTextSearchEnabled` and `TextSearch.TextPath`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Directories, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDirectory, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          EnableRowVirtualization="False"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Name">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" SortMemberPath="Name" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Your Directories collection had a filter applied? Do you have to bind to TextSearch.Text ?

Comment: No the collection didn't have a filter applied. And you don't need to bind to `TextSearch.Text`, it should just be a string value representing the name of the property you want to perform the textsearch on.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm going to have to go a bit deeper because I just can't grasp how that is working like that. Maybe I am confusing it with a filter.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I see your confusion. The TextSearch is just meant for a quick way to select the right item in the list by typing the first few characters of the value you're looking for. It doesn't do any filtering at all.